# Lots of routes declared in Symfony project, but cannot GET any of them

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing

I'm trying to set up an extant Symfony project on my local machine.

I made it far enough to get the project running, but when I browse to any of the routes in the router, I get this error:

```
No route found for "GET /users/"
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
1 linked Exception:

ResourceNotFoundException » 

DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Nelmio\CorsBundle\EventListener\CorsListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelException".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener::onKernelException".
ERROR - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /"" at /Users/james/code/REDACTED/REDACTED/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1880
```

When I `$ php console router:debug` I get dozens of routes, including the /users/ routes:

```
intranet_users                                                     ANY    ANY    {domain}      /users/
intranet_user_create                                               ANY    ANY    {domain}      /users/create
intranet_user                                                      ANY    ANY    {domain}      /users/{username}
```

What gives? Why does every route I browse to on localhost:8000 result in a Symfony error page?

Comment: php bin/console router:match "/users/" to check

Comment: Can  you show the route definition? Are there any additional restrictions, e.g. domain, schema or expressions filtering for a specific header?

Comment: @dbrumann, I believe that my {domain} didn't match what was expected from the config files. I've got it working now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with the project lead dev, I was told I need to set the project up with a Docker container rather than in my local environment.

I think the reason I wasn't getting routing to work is that the domain I was hosting on locally didn't match the expected {domain} from the router config file. I was trying to access via `localhost` while the expected domain was `intranet.localhost`.

Coming from a Rails background, I wasn't used to routing being so picky with domains.

Comment: Symfony does not care about the host name by default. However, you *can* bind routes to a host name, and this seems to be the case in your project.

Comment: @lxg That must be the case, thank you for the insight.